# PHP E-mail Script not working. What's wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sendmail

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<?php include 'header_admin.php'; ?>
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
page_protect();
checkAdmin();
?>
<?PHP
require_once "Mail.php";

$con = mysql_connect("host","username","pass");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

$elist = mysql_query("SELECT cEmail FROM tblUsers WHERE intUserID = '20'");

$from = "FROM E-MAIL";
$subject = $_POST['eSubject'];
$body = $_POST['eMessage'];

$host = "smtp.domain.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

echo "<div class='entry'>"; 

if(mysql_num_rows($elist) > 0)
{                   
    while($eresult = @mysql_fetch_array($elist)) {
        $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $eresult['cEmail'], 'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($elist_result['cEmail'], $headers, $body);
    }   
}

echo "<table align='center'><p>Message successfully sent!</p></table></div>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I made sure that the smtp settings were correct and I manually checked my mysql query to make sure it's grabbing the e-mail address. also, I did a separate "echo" command to make sure $body and $subject were correct.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's "not working?" Are there error messages? Have you checked your error and mail log files?

Comment: How do I check the log files. THere are NO errors. I'm not receiving the e-mail. I checked the smtp through gmail servers and it's working, just not through this script

Comment: might be your ISP ignores the smtp protocols that your PC sends out

Comment: You need to find out from your ISP how you can see the web server error logs.  That's where you'll find the error messages that are the key to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

You use there `$elist_result['cEmail']` , if it differs from `$eresult['cEmail']` , where does it come from?
Its not obvious from the code posted above.(guess it's just a typing error)

Comment: That's a typo. It's the $eresult['cEmail'] the result from the sql query

Answer (score 0):

The `$smtp->send()` method returns a PEAR_Error object if something blows up (or boolean TRUE if the call succeeded). Change your code to something like this:

```
$ret = $smtp->send();
if ($ret !== TRUE) {
    echo "Mail send failed: ", $err::getMessage();
}
```

which should echo out any details of the failure for you.